# How to deserialize json property with json content

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this json:

```
{
"Entity":"MP3",
"Body":"{"name":"COKE","category":"CANDIES","sales":123.0}"
}
```

As you can see Body property contains json content. How to deserialize it? I am using NewtonJson and getting this error:

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: n. Path 'Body', line 1,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientJsonData>(jsonDecode)

public class ClientJsonData
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
}
```

My root class contains Entity and Body string properties

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: That's not valid json. Get rid of the quote before `{` and after `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is not valid JSON. It needs to look like this if you intend for the body to be an object.

```json
{
    "Entity":"MP3",
    "Body": {"name":"COKE","category":"CANDIES","sales":123.0}
}
```

or this, which escapes the quotes, if you intend for the body to be a string

```json
{
    "Entity":"MP3",
    "Body": "{\"name\":\"COKE\",\"category\":\"CANDIES\",\"sales\":123.0}"
}
```

As your .NET object has two strings, it appears you want the latter.

After you do that, you can use the JSON.NET API as usual

```cs
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientJsonData>(myInput);
```